# Как исправить ошибку TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Tags: python, discord.py

Код:

```py
import discord
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print ("Logged on as {0}!".format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self,message):
        print("Message from {0.author}: {0.content}".format(message))

client = MyClient()
client.run('тута токен')
```

Ошибка:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\askha\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\BOT\bot.py", line 10, in <module>
    client = MyClient()
             ^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents
```

Comment: `client = MyClient()` - ну так передайте ему то, что он просит

Answer (score 1):

Данная ошибка вызвана тем, что ты пытаешься инициализировать клиент без использования Intents, что ныне является обязательным.

К примеру, подобный к твоему исправленный код:

```py
import discord
from discord import Intents

intents = Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True 

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print ("Logged on as {0}!".format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self,message):
        print("Message from {0.author}: {0.content}".format(message))

client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('Токен')
```

А вообще, лучше сесть и прочесть документацию:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Если нужно что-то по-проще:

https://vk.com/@helish88-intents-chto-eto-takoe-i-s-chem-edyat

Comment: А можете объяснить тогда в чем та же ошибка в другом моем вопросе?

Comment: @Yunuu Так там та же самая ошибка про интенты